# Draw Gestalt laws of grouping with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce an illustration of the Gestalt laws of grouping.

For instance, this image

[image]

or

[image]

without symmetry and periodicity. But eventually also other figures that are easier to draw with tikz.

I have tried with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% proximity
\begin{scope}
\draw (0,1) -- (0,-1);
\draw (0.2,1) -- (0.2,-1);

\draw (0.6,1) -- (0.6,-1);
\draw (0.8,1) -- (0.8,-1);

\draw (1.2,1) -- (1.2,-1);
\draw (1.4,1) -- (1.4,-1);

\node at (0.7,-1.5) {Proximity};
\end{scope}

% connectedness
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\node [draw,circle,fill] at (0,0.8)   (a) {};
\node [draw,circle,fill] at (1.4,0.8) (b) {};
\draw (a) -- (b);

\node [draw,circle,fill] at (0,0)   (a) {};
\node [draw,circle,fill] at (1.4,0) (b) {};
\draw (a) -- (b);

\node [draw,circle,fill] at (0,-0.8)   (a) {};
\node [draw,circle,fill] at (1.4,-0.8) (b) {};
\draw (a) -- (b);

\node at (0.7,-1.5) {Connectedness};
\end{scope}

% similarity
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\end{scope}

% continuity
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\end{scope}

% closure
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

the code is not very good, and I only produce these two

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Im not familiar with Gestalt laws of grouping, so I try to re-code two your picture's code and draw two more, which you mentioned in code and draw two more mentioned in code and showed in question.

In first attempt I preserve your approach to use `scope` for grouping images, however, I estimate, that more simple approach is broke images on sub-images and than they include for example in table  or in `subfigure`s of `figure` (use of package `subcaption`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
FN/.style = {% Fit Node
    inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=6pt, label=below:#1,
    node contents={}
            },
                    ]
% proximity
\begin{scope}[thick]
\draw   (0.0,0) coordinate (a)  
                -- + (0,2)      (0.2,0) -- + (0,2)
        (0.6,0) -- + (0,2)      (0.8,0) -- + (0,2)
        (1.2,0) -- + (0,2)      (1.4,0) -- + (0,2) coordinate (b);
\node[FN=Proximity, fit=(a) (b)];
\end{scope}

% connectedness
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,
              every path/.style={{Circle[width=3mm,length=3mm]}-%
                                 {Circle[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}]
\draw   (0,0) coordinate (a)
              edge + (2,0)    
        (0,1) edge + (2,0)
        (0,2)  to  + (2,0) coordinate (b);
\node[FN=Connectedness, fit=(a) (b)];
\end{scope}

% similarity
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,
              node distance=0.5cm,
              TF/.style={regular polygon=,regular polygon sides=3,fill=blue,
                         node contents={}},
              TO/.style={regular polygon=,regular polygon sides=3,draw=blue,
                         node contents={}}
              ]
\node (a1) [TF,above];          \node (b1) [TO,right=of a1];  \node (c1) [TF,right=of b1];
\node (a2) [TF,above=of a1];    \node (b2) [TO,right=of a2];  \node (c2) [TF,right=of b2];
\node (a3) [TF,above=of a2];    \node (b3) [TO,right=of a3];  \node (c3) [TF,right=of b3];
\node[FN=Similarity, fit=(a1) (c3)];
\end{scope}

% continuity
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (5*pi/5,2);
\draw(0,1) -- + (3,0);
\draw plot[domain=0/2:5*pi,, samples=100]  (\x/5,{1-cos(\x r)});
\node[FN=Continuity, fit=(a) (b)];
\end{scope}

% closure
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Graphs presentation of Gestalt laws as sub images is simpler than draw one (huge) common image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.geometric}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\subfloat[Proximity]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw   (0,0) -- + (0,2)      (0.3,0) -- + (0,2)
        (1,0) -- + (0,2)      (1.3,0) -- + (0,2)
        (2,0) -- + (0,2)      (2.3,0) -- + (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfil
\subfloat[Connectedness]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
every path/.style={{Circle[width=3mm,length=3mm]}-%
                   {Circle[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}]
\draw   (0,0) edge + (3,0)
        (0,1) edge + (3,0)
        (0,2)  to  + (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}\\

\subfloat[Connectedness]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0.5cm,
    TF/.style={regular polygon=,regular polygon sides=3,fill=blue,
               node contents={}},
    TO/.style={regular polygon=,regular polygon sides=3,draw=blue,
               node contents={}}
                    ]
\node (a1) [TF];                     \node (b1) [TO,right=of a1];  \node [TF,right=of b1];
\node (a2) [TF,above=of a1];    \node (b2) [TO,right=of a2];  \node [TF,right=of b2];
\node (a3) [TF,above=of a2];    \node (b3) [TO,right=of a3];  \node [TF,right=of b3];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfil
\subfloat[Continuity]%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,1) -- + (3,0);
\draw plot[domain=0/2:5*pi,, samples=100]  (\x/5,{1-cos(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Gestalt laws of grouping}
\label{fig:gestalt}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]